# vuejs hover example not clearly understood

Tags: vue.js, hover

[I am beginner learning vuejs and not getting that how it is showing the message on hover effect when it is not mentioned anywhere that it should display the message with black background and with white color text, when the user is hovering on the message. Can anyone help to understand this vuejs example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiLOV.png)

Comment: you can do that by just adding title in html tag

Comment: okay thanx a lot, I actually got confused between the title tag and hover effect in html.